# What is faster one concurrent queue or 8 lock-free queue?

Tags: c++, concurrency

I have 8 threads on client side (producer) and 1 thread on server side (consumers)

Consumer thread is spinning checking if new data arrives. I have two options to implement this:

- use one [concurrent queue](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_queue_cls.htm),  all 8 producers post to same queue, server spin and `try_pop` it
- use 8 lock-free [single producer single consumer queue](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.html). each producer post to own queue, but consumer should check 8 queries instead of just one.

As I think checking 8 lock-free queries must be significantly faster than checking one blocking queue (cause blocking is expensive!). So I tend to use 8 spsc_queue. If I'm right and what can you suggest?

Comment: No idea. Which was faster when you tested each option?

Comment: You could make it faster by not spinning.

Comment: how many tests do you need to perform to be sure that ferrari is faster than a donkey?

Comment: @javapowered ["ferrari is faster than a donkey"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XeI--gNjfjg) Environment matters!

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends heavily on your system architecture.  So first of all, check with [`harware_concrurrency()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency/)  if your 8 threads could really run in parrallel:

- if you have enough free hardware cores (and if they are not taken by other processes),  your spinning may actually improve throughput on client size by using all hardware capacity.  In such case, a single locking queue, would slow down the client side cores : the queue synchronisation might be their bottleneck, forcing them to run one after the other.  If you have 8 separate queues only one will be slowed down by the consumer.
- if not, then each some threads will always be waiting while others are working.  In such case, the single locking queue should not have a significant effect on the overall performance.   But the spinning would not improve performance (in fact, context switching might even decrease it a little bit) and it should be considerd with a critical mind.
- In both case, the single consumer can only process one item at a time. For the consumption it shouldn't make a huge difference if it reads from 8 queues or from 1.

But as you see the matter is complex.  If producer would run at a different pace (higher priority or on another processor, or the consuming code is significantly shorter than the producing code)  the analysis would need to be reconsidered.  So it's advisable to foresee some benchmarks (end to end throughput).